# Convert nested foreach loop into a stream

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, java-stream

I'm trying to convert two `foreach` loops and an `if` statement into a stream.

Here is what I want to convert:

```
for (ViewFlightRouteAirportType associatedAirportType : etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes) {

    for (ViewFlightAirportDTO airport : flightRoute.getAirportsForType(associatedAirportType)) {

        if ( airportIataCode.equals(airport.getIataCode()) ) {
            addValueIfNotPresent(associatedFlights, associatedAirportType, flightData);
        }
    }
}
```

`etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes` is an array.

`airportIataCode` is String

Here is what I wrote:

```
Arrays.stream(etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes)
                .forEach(associatedAirportType -> flightRoute.getAirportsForType(associatedAirportType)
                        .forEach(airport -> flightRoute.getAirportsForType(associatedAirportType)
                                .stream()
                                .filter(p -> p.equals(airport.getIataCode())).forEach(addValueIfNotPresent(associatedFlights,associatedAirportType,flightData);
```

It is not needed and doesn't work, but for me it looks ugly. How should it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I expect your airport has a `getViewFlightRouteAirportType()` getter which makes this easier on us as we don't have to track the value of the current type of the `etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes` array:

```
Arrays.stream(etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes)
        .map(flightRoute::getAirportsForType)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(airport -> airportIataCode.equals(airport.getIataCode()))
        .forEach(airport -> addValueIfNotPresent(associatedFlights, airport.getViewFlightRouteAirportType(), flightData));
```

EDIT: As discussed in the comments

```
for (ViewFlightRouteAirportType associatedAirportType : etopsAndNonEtopsAssociatedAirportTypes) {
    flightRoute.getAirportsForType(associatedAirportType).stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(airport -> airportIataCode.equals(airport.getIataCode()))
            .forEach(airport -> addValueIfNotPresent(associatedFlights, associatedAirportType, flightData));
}
```

Comment: It doesnt have getter.

Comment: Why does your airport not know what type it is?

Comment: It knows. It is iterated in first foreach loop. In `associatedAirportType` we got type. I need to do this this way.

Comment: I would leave the outer for-loop for readability then. It will get ugly with streams (you have to use temporary maps and stream on entrySets)

Comment: Could you paste the whole code with outer for-loop then? I got confused.

Comment: Please note that using `forEach` is mostly frowned upon when using streams as functional programming is all about side-effect free-ness. Normally you would do a collect at the end but as I don't know how `addValueIfNotPresent` I left it as is with `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Since I don't have your classes, I tried to mock it this way. Imagine `ll` is your outer for loop data structure, and for each element in there you create another collection and loop through it. So, basically, we the list of those objects in the inner for loop as a whole collection so that we can filter them. That's where you can use `flatMap` which flattens a collection of collections. Then we just filter and collect those values.

```java
List<String> ll = new ArrayList<>();

ll.stream()
        .map(el-> Arrays.asList(el))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(el->el.equals(str))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Again, I want to mention, this is not the exact case of yours, but I think the situation is similar.

Comment: nah it does not help. Which classes do you need exactly? I dont think you need any of my classes. All types you can  deduce from code.

Comment: What exactly didn't help?

Comment: Im begginer in streams. I cannot deduce anything from your answer.

Comment: I suggest you to read more about `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc. and how those constructs represent an implicit iteration. Technically, if you are new and want to convert from a traditional `for` loop to `Stream`s, you will probably use `forEach` more often and nest them. That shouldn't be the case. Try to read more about those. [Java 8 Lambdas: Functional Programming For The Masses](https://www.amazon.com/Java-Lambdas-Functional-Programming-Masses/dp/1449370772) is a good book that I have personally read and liked.